# Solidworks mechanism to blender

Tags: import

I have a movable assembly in SolidWorks that I wan to import to blender, to ultimately use in Unity. I want the mechanism to be movable in blender too.
How would you suggest I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the scope of your question, what are you having a problem with, are you losing your animation on export?